# How to detect a touch event outside the activity border

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, android-activity

> I have activity A over activity B. Activity A does not fill the entire screen.(Its not dialog activity though)I want to close activity A when the touch event is detected outside the activity A border. how to detect a touch event outside the activity border?

@Override

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi", 3000).show();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

> This code doesn't work as it works only for dialog activities. Please help..Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Activity A does not fill the entire screen.(Its not dialog activity though)..then what it is.?..You may be not using full screen..but its occupying the whole.. you can set x,y limit if exceed u can do such operation

Comment: @manmohan its not necessary that an activity fills the entire screen. ...I have padded the activity to make it appear as a dialog activity

Comment: U can take theme dialog for activity besides padding.and If i think as u r saying then tell can any other activity or something else use that remaining space.suppose if touch is out of activty bounds then how activity will get it now.to clear you more Windowmanager get all the touchevent becoz  its a instance whole Display.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if this works, so please test it :)
but it should be pretty easy:

in actvity A's `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set us to non-modal, so that others can receive the outside touch events.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    //and watch for outside touch events too
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);

    //be sure to set the content view after setting those flags!!
    setContentView(R.layout.my_view);
}
```

now you receive touch events in normal `onTouch()'
just check there if it's outside (get x and y and check against your window's position)

Comment: Why are you adding each flag twice?